# How to split & concatenate JSON array input

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to Javascript, so need some help with the below scenario.

I am reading a JSON input as shown below

```
let json_input = "[
    {
        \"src_AccountId\":[\"00100027H3QAK\"],
        \"src_AccountName\":[\"Vis Card Services\",\"Vitoria Card Services SA\"],
        \"src_MaxVus\":[15,3],
        \"src_DocCount\":[15,3]
    },
    {
        \"src_AccountId\":[\"0010J000027lVFDQA2\",\"6516983c9d71be4bcd799313\"],
        \"src_AccountName\":[\"Semiconductor Components\",\"asdadasda\"],
        \"src_MaxVus\":[880,50],
        \"src_DocCount\":[19,10]
    }]";
```

How can I split & concatenate the input JSON data in order to get the below output? So basically I want 4 arrays each for AccountId, AccountName, MaxVus and DocCount. Also if there is more than 1 accountname for a particular accountid then I want only one accountname to be included in the result based on account which has highest value for MaxVus.

```
[
    {
        "AccountId": [
            "00100027H3QAK",
            "0010J000027lVFDQA2",
            "6516983c9d71be4bcd799313"
        ],
        "AccountName": [
            "Vis Card Services",
            "Semiconductor Components",
            "asdadasda"
        ],
        "DocCount": [
            "15",
            "19",
            "10"
        ],
        "MaxVus": [
            "15",
            "880",
            "50"
        ]
    }
]
```

Thanks

UPDATE

Example2

```
var json_input = "[
    {
        \"src_AccountId\":[\"00100027H3QAK\"],
        \"src_AccountName\":[\"Vis Card Services\",\"Vitoria Card Services SA\"],
        \"src_MaxVus\":[5,30],
        \"src_DocCount\":[2,50]
    },
    {
        \"src_AccountId\":[\"0010J000027lVFDQA2\",\"6516983c9d71be4bcd799313\"],
        \"src_AccountName\":[\"Semiconductor Components\",\"asdadasda\"],
        \"src_MaxVus\":[880,50],
        \"src_DocCount\":[19,10]
    }]";
```

Expected output

```
[{"AccountId":["00100027H3QAK","0010J000027lVFDQA2","6516983c9d71be4bcd799313"],"AccountName":["Vitoria Card Services SA","Semiconductor Components","asdadasda"],"DocCount":["50","19","10"],"MaxVus":["30","880","50"]}]
```

Comment: Hi Vikas, what have you tried so far, and what are the results? You've described what you want, that just needs to be translated into code...

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the JSON first, then iterate over the objects within it, and construct the output in the structure you want.

**Demo:**

```js
var json_input = "[{\"src_AccountId\":[\"00100027H3QAK\"],\"src_AccountName\":[\"Vis Card Services\",\"Vitoria Card Services SA\"],\"src_MaxVus\":[15,3],\"src_DocCount\":[15,3]},{\"src_AccountId\":[\"0010J000027lVFDQA2\",\"6516983c9d71be4bcd799313\"],\"src_AccountName\":[\"Semiconductor Components\",\"asdadasda\"],\"src_MaxVus\":[880,50],\"src_DocCount\":[19,10]}]";

var data = JSON.parse(json_input); //parse the JSON input
var output = {
  "AccountId": [],
  "AccountName": [],
  "DocCount": [],
  "MaxVus": []
  
};

//iterate over the objects
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var src_AccountId = data[i].src_AccountId;
  var src_AccountName = data[i].src_AccountName;
  var src_MaxVus = data[i].src_MaxVus;
  var src_DocCount = data[i].src_DocCount;

  for (var j = 0; j < src_AccountId.length; j++) {
    //if the AccountId is not already in the output, add it along with the corresponding values
    if (!output.AccountId.includes(src_AccountId[j])) {
      output.AccountId.push(src_AccountId[j]);
      output.AccountName.push(src_AccountName[j]);
      output.MaxVus.push(src_MaxVus[j]);
      output.DocCount.push(src_DocCount[j]);
    } else {
      //if the AccountId is already in the output, update values based on MaxVus
      var index = output.AccountId.indexOf(src_AccountId[j]);
      if (src_MaxVus[j] > output.MaxVus[index]) {
        output.AccountName[index] = src_AccountName[j];
        output.MaxVus[index] = src_MaxVus[j];
        output.DocCount[index] = src_DocCount[j];
      }
    }
  }
}

//convert the values to strings (as per your example)
output.MaxVus = output.MaxVus.map(String);
output.DocCount = output.DocCount.map(String);

//put the result in an array
var result = [output];
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)); //output the result
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mamun However, in the output, if there is more than 1 account name for a particular accountid then I want only one accountname to be included in the result based on account which has highest value for MaxVus. But with above code I am still getting always the first account name even if its MaxVus is less.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```js
const json_input = `[{
        \"src_AccountId\":[\"00100027H3QAK\"],
        \"src_AccountName\":[\"Vis Card Services\",\"Vitoria Card Services SA\"],
        \"src_MaxVus\":[15,3],
        \"src_DocCount\":[15,3]
    },
    {
        \"src_AccountId\":[\"0010J000027lVFDQA2\",\"6516983c9d71be4bcd799313\"],
        \"src_AccountName\":[\"Semiconductor Components\",\"asdadasda\"],
        \"src_MaxVus\":[880,50],
        \"src_DocCount\":[19,10]
    }]`;

const data = JSON.parse(json_input);

const AccountId = [];
const AccountName = [];
const DocCount = [];
const MaxVus = [];

for (let obj of data) {
  for (let i = 0; i < obj.src_AccountId.length; i++) {
    const index = AccountId.indexOf(obj.src_AccountId[i]);
    if (index === -1) {
      AccountId.push(obj.src_AccountId[i]);
      AccountName.push(obj.src_AccountName[i]);
      DocCount.push(obj.src_DocCount[i]);
      MaxVus.push(obj.src_MaxVus[i]);
    } else {

      if (obj.src_MaxVus[i] > MaxVus[index]) {
        AccountName[index] = obj.src_AccountName[i];
        MaxVus[index] = obj.src_MaxVus[i];
      }
    }
  }
}

const output = [{
  AccountId,
  AccountName,
  DocCount,
  MaxVus
}];

console.log(output);
```

**Code Explanation:**

```
1. Parse the JSON input into a JavaScript object.
2. Define variables to store result.
3. Iterate over the parsed Object.
4. If the AccountId doesn't exist in the AccountId array, or the new MaxVus is greater, add it and the other values
5. If the AccountId already exists in the AccountId array, remove it and its associated values
```

Comment: Thanks, @mandy8055 However, in the output, if there is more than 1 account name for a particular accountid then I want only one accountname to be included in the result based on account which has highest value for MaxVus. But with above code I am still getting always the first account name even if its MaxVus is less.

Comment: @VikasJ, can you provide one example?

Comment: Hello @mandy8055 I have updated my post, please refer UPDATE section, so basically in this case also there is 1 accountId which has 2 accountname, doccount, maxvus, in such case, in the outout we should see accountname,doccount,maxvus for Vitoria Card Services SA as its maxVus is 30 instead of 5 for Vis Card Services